# c# methods not running in the sequence I wrote them

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I got two standard projects in a solution. The UI and the Logic.
As usual, you need to take the inputs from the UI and do whatever you want with them in the back end part.

So in the UI class, I have this

```
        private void btnAddItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        item_name = lbl_item_name.Text;
        item_quantity = lbl_item_quantity.Text;
        store_ime = store_Name.Text;


        logika.storeInDb(store_ime, item_name, item_quantity);
    }
```

It just stores the input in variables and then sends them to this

```
        public void storeInDb(string store_name, string item_name, string item_quantity)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(Logic.connStr))
        {
            dbInsert($"INSERT INTO soping(store_name, item_name, item_quantity, payment_type, date) VALUES('{store_name}', '{item_name}', '{item_quantity}', 'visa', 'danas')");
        }
    }
```

And this is the dbInsert method

```
        public void dbInsert(string query)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mySqlConn = new MySqlConnection(Logic.connStr))
        {
            try
            {
                mySqlConn.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySqlConn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                mySqlConn.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't store anything. And when I use breakpoints, it seems like the button method runs after storeInDb, even though the variables in the query are perfectly fine. And I can't find anything wrong with the code that would make it behave weird like this.

Comment: so what do you get  ?

Comment: So… many... bad... practices. I also do not see where you are having a problem (though you create two connections for no reason)

Comment: What actually happens that is unexpected? it is unclear; note: using `$"...{whatever}..."` to build SQL is *really, really* dangerous (SQL injection, localization, etc) - and there's a good chance it is the cause of your problem, even without knowing what the problem is

Comment: The two connections were my bad, and I understand that storing data like that is horrible. The problem is that it doesn't work. It should from what I see, I've checked the database information and I can't find anything odd.

Comment: The 2 connections might be the core problem. Do remove one.

Comment: I have removed it, It's still not adding. I'm not seeing any MySql Exceptions either.

Comment: Alright, after looking through it I realized that I had a store_id foreign key set to not null in the table, yet I wasn't inserting anything into it. After removing the not null, works fine.
Though, I'd still love to hear about the so many bad practices @BradleyDotNET. Excluding the two connections and storing the data using one string, is there anything else that's very bad about the code? Excluding using Dapper or similar orm's, I'd love to know.

Comment: Concatenated string SQL over parameterized queries, not using MVVM, not threading the DB call, it looks like you have class level variables in your UI class that could probably be local. I'm going to take a wild guess and say "Logic" is pretty monolithic and could use some encapsulation. Also, your naming convention is off (methods should be PascalCase). I'd strongly recommend an ORM but not using one isn't strictly a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

This code have some issues:

1- You should use parameters instead of direct strings in your sql query;

2- You don't need a connection outside your dbInsert Method

However, this code **should** work. I guess the problem you are having is located **elsewhere**, not in the code you posted here. Something simpler, maybe connectionstring problem (saving in other place where you don't expect to) or bad uses of threads...Maybe hitting deadlocks, long processing or something like that (the only way i can think of having button click apparently happenning **after** the code it calls).